# sudo doesn't working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, groups, su

I am going to update packages in *Ubuntu 22.04* terminal.

```
sudo apt update
```

But I get errors like this.

```
tester@ubuntu22.04-lts:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for user:
tester is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.
```

So, I am trying to add user to sudo group.
But su command also encountered an error.

```
tester@ubuntu22.04-lts:~$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure
```

I'm hesitating on how to deal with the problem.

I think "tester" user has been deleted from sudo group, is there any solution?

And here is one addition, it's as follows.

```
tester@ubuntu22.04-tls:~$ groups tester

tester : tester
```